# How can I enumerate an object inside another object?

Tags: javascript, enumeration

I'm trying to enumerate z, displaying its properties z1, z2, z3.

```
function foo()
{
  var o = {x:1,y:2,z:{z1:3,z2:4,z3:5}};
  for(prop in o)
  {

  }    
}
```

Comment: Why did you stop? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: try checking if 'prop' is an object and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
var o = {x:1,y:2,z:{z1:3,z2:4,z3:5}};
iterate(o);   

function iterate(o) {
    var key, item;
    for (key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            item = o[key];
            if (typeof item === 'object') {
                iterate(item);
            } else {
                console.log(key, item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was banging my head for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function foo(){
  var o = {x:1,y:2,z:{z1:3,z2:4,z3:5}};
  var z = o.z;
  for(var i in z){
    // i is property
    // z[i] is value
  }    
}
```